# wp_script_add_data not working

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

We are trying to add "async" to our script using this code. However this is not added by wordpress. Not sure why it's not doing anything.

```
function wp_mk_scripts() {

    if ( is_page(26202) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'pledge-js', 'https://www.pledge.to/assets/widget.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        wp_script_add_data( 'pledge-js', 'async', true );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_mk_scripts' );
```

We only want to add the async tag to this particular script without affecting any other scripts on our site which might be loaded by the same function.

Answer (score 1):

the `wp_script_add_data()` method itself is not adding async attribute to the script tag. It just add a metadata to the script.

As examples were already given earlier in few answers the following could work for you:

```
wp_enqueue_script('pledge-js', 'https://www.pledge.to/assets/widget.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);
wp_script_add_data( 'pledge-js', 'async', true);

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'async_scripts', 3, 10);

function async_scripts($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if (wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, 'async')) {

        $tag = str_replace( '<script src', '<script async src', $tag );
        // you can do also: $tag = str_replace( '></', ' async></', $tag );
    }

    return $tag;
}
```

After you add the data to your script then you have to filter the script tag to add 'async' attribute to the script's html tag (only at scripts which have that metadata `('async', true)` added), so you can use this filter/function on many scripts where you want `async` attributes added to the tag.